# How to connect to sqlite database on environmental path

Tags: java, sqlite

i have my sqlite.db file on that path: C:\Users\napster89\AppData\Roaming\sqlite.db

this is my code:

```
Connection connection = null;
      try
      {
         // create a database connection
         connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:(\"%APPDATA%\\sqlite.db\")");
....
```

this code generate error, How can i connect to it using DriverManager.getConnection?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expand the Windows environment with `String.format()` and `System.getenv()`:

```
String url = String.format("jdbc:sqlite:%s\\sqlite.db", System.getenv("APPDATA"));
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url );
```

Comment: sir it doesn't work it generate an error :                                                                               
 path to '(C:\Users\napster89\AppData\Roaming\sqlite.db)': 'C:\Users\napster89\Desktop\CopyDate\CopyDate\(C:' does not exist                                                   when i use this line it works                                                                                            
 String url = ("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\napster89\\AppData\\Roaming\\sqlite.db");

Comment: I missed out some quotes you used inside the driver url, but are you sure you need the `("` and `")` around the path? This should work: `String.format("jdbc:sqlite:%s\\sqlite.db", System.getenv("APPDATA"))`